# pandas: create another data frame using existing data frame from the given index position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe where I have one another list of index position based on some condition so just want to create the new dataframe based on the index position and check some condition on that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['index'] = [ 0, 28, 35, 49, 85, 105, 208, 386, 419, 512, 816, 888, 914, 989]
df['diff_in_min'] = [ 5, 35, 42, 46, 345, 85, 96, 107, 119, 325, 8, 56, 55, 216]
df['val_1'] = [5, 25, 2, 4, 2, 5, 69, 6, 8, 7, 55, 85, 8, 67]
df['val_2'] = [8, 89, 8, 5, 7, 57, 8, 57, 4, 8, 74, 65, 55, 74]
re_ind = list(np.where(df['diff_in_min'] >= 300))
re_ind = [np.array([85, 512], dtype='int64')]
```

Just I want to create another dataframe based on re_ind position, ex:

```
first_df = df[0:85] 
another_df = [85:512] 
last_df =  [512:]
```

and each dataframe I want to check one condition

```
count = 0
temp_df = df[:re_ind[0]]
if temp_df['diff_in_min'].sum() > 500:
    count += 1
temp_df = df[re_ind[0]:re_ind[1]]
if temp_df['diff_in_min'].sum() > 500:
    count += 1
if temp_df = df[re_ind[1]:]
if temp_df['diff_in_min'].sum() > 500:
    count += 1
```

How can I do that using for loop with creating new data frame using existing dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sample data for groups created by `df['diff_in_min'] >= 300)` add cumulative sum, then aggregate `sum`, compare for another condition and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
s = (df['diff_in_min'] >= 300).cumsum()

out = (df['diff_in_min'].groupby(s).sum() > 500).sum()
print (out)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

jezrael's answer is much better and more succinct. However, in keeping with your style of programming, here is another way you could tackle it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['index'] = [ 0, 28, 35, 49, 85, 105, 208, 386, 419, 512, 816, 888, 914, 989]
df['diff_in_min'] = [ 5, 35, 42, 46, 345, 85, 96, 107, 119, 325, 8, 56, 55, 216]
df['val_1'] = [5, 25, 2, 4, 2, 5, 69, 6, 8, 7, 55, 85, 8, 67]
df['val_2'] = [8, 89, 8, 5, 7, 57, 8, 57, 4, 8, 74, 65, 55, 74]

df_list = []
df_list.append(df[df['index']<85])
df_list.append(df[(df['index']>=85) & (df['index'] <512)])
df_list.append(df[df['index']>=512])

count = 0
for temp_df in df_list:
    if temp_df['diff_in_min'].sum() > 500:
        count += 1

print(f"Count = {count}")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Count = 2
```

Which is exactly what jezrael got, and why my vote goes to them.

Comment: you created df_list manually if it this list contains more than 50 int then will not useful your code.

Comment: given an example with more than 50, then I probably would have tackled it differently. However, I was trying to keep inline with your programming style - not mine :)